# regex to match partial strings and fragments of sentences

Tags: regex

Suppose I wish to match the following with a regular expression:

```
Convert 2g of NaOH into moles.
Convert 3.2 grams of Chlorine into mol.
How many moles are in 67 g of Sodium Chloride?
434 mol of Sodium to Grams.
```

The requirements are:

- Both the terms `g`/`grams` *and* `mol`/`moles` need to appear in the string
- These terms must be on their own, i.e. not as parts of longer words like `molecules`.

**How could I use a single regex to match all 4 cases?**

So far I have tried this:

```
~'mol|g|Grams/g
```

but it also matches terms such as:

```
32 mol
gravity of molecule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex requires both "mol"/"moles" and "g"/"grams" (allowing the "g" to immediately follow a digit):

```
/^(?=.*\bmol(es)?\b)(?=.*[^a-z](g|grams?)\b).*/i
```

The use of `\b` - word boundary - ensures "molecule" and "good" don't count as matches etc.

The "i" flag makes it case insensitive.

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/eRxJ4ICdbr)