# python how to match partial strings between two unequal sized columns

Tags: python, pandas

Very new to Python here, and still am quite not fully understanding how to use Python correctly, so please bear with my stupidity here.

Let's say we have a dataframe like this:

```
samp_data = pd.DataFrame([[1,'hello there',3],
                             [4,'im just saying hello',6],
                             [7,'but sometimes i say bye',9],
                             [2,'random words here',5]],
                            columns=["a", "b", "c"])
print(samp_data)
   a                        b  c
0  1              hello there  3
1  4     im just saying hello  6
2  7  but sometimes i say bye  9
3  2        random words here  5
```

and we set a list of words we dont want:

```
unwanted_words = ['hello', 'random']
```

I want to write a function that will **exclude all rows where column b contains any words in the "unwanted_words" list**. So the output should be:

```
print(samp_data)
   a                        b  c
2  7  but sometimes i say bye  9
```

what i've tried so far include using the built in "isin()" function:

```
data = samp_data.ix[samp_data['b'].isin(unwanted_words),:]
```

but this does not exclude the rows as i expected; 
and I tried using the str.contains() function:

```
for i,row in samp_data.iterrows():
    if unwanted_words.str.contains(row['b']).any():
        print('found matching words')
```

and this would throw me errors.

i think i'm just complicating things and there must be some really easy way out there that I am not aware of. 
any help is greatly appreciated!

posts i read into so far (not limited to this list, as i closed many windows already):

- [regex to match partial strings and fragments of sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668278/regex-to-match-partial-strings-and-fragments-of-sentences)
- [Check if a value in one column is in a list in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233069/check-if-a-value-in-one-column-is-in-a-list-in-another-column)
- [Check if column value is in other columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093394/check-if-column-value-is-in-other-columns-in-pandas)

Comment: You should tag your question with "panda". This is not pure Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually really close to the solution. It uses the method Series.str.contains. Just remember that it allows for regular expression:

```
samp_data[~samp_data['b'].str.contains(r'hello|random')]
```

Result will be:

```
Out [11]:
    a                         b c
2   7   but sometimes i say bye 9
```

Comment: wow thanks! i like your solution the best! one line and similar to what i was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most elegant but I think it will work for you?

```
def in_excluded(my_str, excluded):
    """
    (str) -> bool
    """
    for each in my_str:
        if each in excluded:
            return True
    return False


def print_only_wanted(samp_data, excluded):
    """
    (list, list) -> None
    Prints each of the lists in the main list unless they contain a word 
    from excluded
    """
    for each in samp_data:
        if not in_excluded(each, excluded):
            print each
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` to determine whether one string can be found within another string. For example, `"he" in "hello"` will return `True`. You can combine this with a list comprehension and the `any` function to select the rows you want:

```
df_sub = samp_data.loc[samp_data['b'].apply(lambda x: not(any([badword in x for badword in unwanted_words]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use str.contains

```
samp_data = samp_data[~samp_data.b.str.contains('hello|random')]
```

You get

```
    a   b                       c
2   7   but sometimes i say bye 9
```

If your list of unwanted words is longer, you may want to use

```
unwanted_words = ['hello', 'random']
samp_data = samp_data[~samp_data.b.str.contains('|'.join(unwanted_words))]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one-liner? I am sure some of the other `pandas` enthusiasts will have some niftier answers than me.

```
samp_data[~samp_data['b'].apply(lambda x: any(word in unwanted_words for word in x.split()))]

   a                        b  c
2  7  but sometimes i say bye  9
```